# Применение фильтра blur к определенной области изображения SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

У меня есть довольно сложное, динамически созданное svg изображение, которое было реализовано с помощью плагина - [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).
 Я хотел бы создать область `popup`, которая будет отображаться поверх всех элементов svg на холсте.
Для реализации современного полупрозрачного эффекта похожего на `look` в `iOS7`, я бы хотел применить фильтр размытия (blur) ко всем изображениям под всплывающей областью.
Я хочу иметь возможность динамически устанавливать атрибуты x, y, а также изменять ширину и высоту этой всплывающей области.
 Взгляните на этот пример: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcB48/)

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
<rect x="10" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="red" />
<rect x="255" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="green" />
<rect x="10" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="blue" />
<rect x="255" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="yellow" />

<rect x="50" y="50" height="400" width="400" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" />
```

В этом случае всё, что покрыто белой областью, должно быть размытым. Это  выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я нашел пример, но там используется статическое фоновое изображение, которого у меня нет. 
Есть ли какие-либо способы для достижения этого эффекта с помощью  svg, css и jQuery?
Перевод вопроса: [Apply blur filter to certain area of svg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348734/apply-blur-filter-to-certain-area-of-svg-image/19354859#19354859) @[Dafen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566051/dafen)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348734/apply-blur-filter-to-certain-area-of-svg-image/19354859#19354859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так кошернее

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="red" />
    <rect x="255" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="green" />
    <rect x="10" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="blue" />
    <rect x="255" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="yellow" />
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
    <rect id="blur" x="50" y="50" height="400" width="400" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "так кошернее" :) У разных людей на цвет и вкус, как говорится, разные фломастеры. У автора ответа   enSO  Paul LeBeau картинка более близка к оригиналу. Но решение я отдал Вам.

Comment: я спорить не буду ! вам виднее

Answer (score 2):

Как насчет такого подхода? Это немного сложнее в использовании, но, похоже, это работает во всех браузерах.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3X4p/2/)

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewbox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blurry" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur x="50" y="50" width="400" height="400" stdDeviation="40" in="SourceGraphic" result="blurSquares"/>
      <feComponentTransfer in="blurSquares" result="opaqueBlur">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="opaqueBlur" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g id="squares" filter="url(#blurry)">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="red" />
    <rect x="255" y="10" height="235" width="235" fill="green" />
    <rect x="10" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="blue" />
    <rect x="255" y="255" height="235" width="235" fill="yellow" />
  </g>

    <rect x="50" y="50" height="400" width="400" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0.8" />
</svg>
```

Это сложнее, потому что фильтр применяется к фону, а не к `<rect>`. Чтобы он работал, вам нужно скопировать `x`, `y`, `width` и `height` из `<rect>` в примитив `feGaussianBlur`.

[Перевод ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348734/apply-blur-filter-to-certain-area-of-svg-image/19354859#19354859): @[Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)